# How to relate entities that are not directly mapped through a navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an object that has been populated with the contents of four different related entities.  However i have another entity in which i cannot include as part of the query due to it not being related in the navigation properites directly to the IQueryable table i am pulling.  The entity i am trying to include is related to one of the four different entities that have been included successfully.

Is there a way to include(during db hit or afterwards) this entity as part of the overall object i am creating?

Here is an example of what my calls look like to build the CARTITEM object:

```
    public List<CARTITEM> ListCartItem(Guid cartId)
    {
        //Create the Entity object
        List<CARTITEM> itemInfo = null;

        using (Entities webStoreContext = new Entities())
        {
                //Invoke the query
                itemInfo = WebStoreDelegates.selectCartItems.Invoke(webStoreContext).ByCartID(cartId).ToList();

        }

        //Return the result set
        return itemInfo;
    }
```

here is the selectCartItems filter(Where i would normally do the includes):

```
        public static Func<Entities, IQueryable<CARTITEM>> selectCartItems =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<Entities, IQueryable<CARTITEM>>(
        (cart) => from c in cart.CARTITEM.Include("ITEM").Include("SHIPPINGOPTION").Include("RELATEDITEM").Include("PROMOTION")
                  select c);
```

from this i have my CARTITEM object.  Problem is i want to include the PROMOTIONTYPE table in this object, but since the CARTIEM entity doesn't have a navigation property directly to the PROMOTIONTYPE table i get an error.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.
Thanks,
Billy

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and if it is the same database and server it should generate the join in SQL and do it all in one call...

[LinqToEnties join example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx)

Comment: i was unable to join a cross reference table that doesn't show in the entity model.  My CARTITEM table has a cross reference table that links to the PROMOTION table.  Since i was unable to join the to i couldn't get to the PROMOTIONTYPE table.

Comment: i re-wrote this post again under 1683471 and answered my own question.  The delegate should have been:

 public static Func<Entities, IQueryable<CARTITEM>> selectCartItems =    CompiledQuery.Compile<Entities, IQueryable<CARTITEM>>(        (cart) => from c in cart.CARTITEM.Include("ITEM").Include("SHIPPINGOPTION").Include("RELATEDITEM").Include("PROMOTION.PROMOTIONTYPE")                  select c);

as you can see i was missing the .PROMOTIONTYPE